# BigQuery Python client method to output JSON file as shown in UI

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, gcloud

I've got a bunch of BQ queries that exports fine to JSON in the UI, but cannot find anywhere in Python client docs a method that'll export query results to the same JSON output that shows here:

[image: json output]

I get that we can create the JSON in python, but I wrote the queries in a way specifically so that it outputs the JSON that's in the UI.

If the Python client doesn't provide such a method or parameter, can gcloud accomplish this instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

[Use gcloud to schedule query to a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query):

```sh
# SCHEDULE QUERY RESULTS TO DESTINATION TABLE
bq query \
    --use_legacy_sql=false \
    --project_id=my_project_id\
    --destination_table=test_dataset.test_table \
    --display_name='my scheduled query name' \
    --schedule='every 12 hours' \
    --replace=true \ # i.e. overwrite
    "select current_timestamp as dt
    union all
    select timestamp_sub(current_timestamp, interval 1 day)"
```

[Export table to storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in):

```sh
# EXPORT TABLE TO GCS
bq extract \
    --destination_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
    my_project_id:test_dataset.test_table \
    gs://test-bucket-20201218/test_file.json
```

To schedule the second bit (export table to storage) I imagine [Cloud Scheduler API](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com) would do it.